# Can I inject a list of classes that are subtypes of some other type?

Tags: java, spring

Can I inject a list of classes that are subtypes of some other type? This doesn't work

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.util.List;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GenericTest.Config.class)
public class GenericTest {
    @Autowired
    List<Class<? extends StringProvider>> stringProviders;
    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println(); // to stop the debugger, but it never gets here
    }

    interface StringProvider {
        String getString();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public StringProvider stringProviderOne() {
            return () -> "one";
        }

        @Bean
        public StringProvider stringProviderTwo() {
            return () -> "two";
        }
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<java.lang.Class<com.example.dynamicgateway.misc.GenericTest$StringProvider>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I don't want to register `Class` objects as beans

```java
    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public Class<? extends StringProvider> stringProviderOne() {
            return ((StringProvider) () -> "one").getClass();
        }

        @Bean
        public Class<? extends StringProvider> stringProviderTwo() {
            return ((StringProvider) () -> "two").getClass();
        }
    }
```

In case you're wondering why I may need this, imagine you need to (dynamically) check which implementation you need (by calling some static method on each injected class, for instance) and then actually create an object of that subtype, passing some args

Comment: you are doing pretty weird stuff there...why would you want to inject Class objects? are you building a parser, or a compiler? extensions to the runtime, even?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, when you use @Autowired with a List of a certain type, Spring expects to find beans of that type directly, not their Class objects. In your case, you are trying to autowire a List<Class<? extends StringProvider>>, which is not a valid use case for Spring.

If you want to dynamically check implementations and create objects based on some condition, you may consider using a factory pattern. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import java.util.List;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GenericTest.Config.class)
public class GenericTest {

    @Autowired
    List<StringProvider> stringProviders;

    @Test
    void test() {
        for (StringProvider provider : stringProviders) {
            // Dynamically check and create objects based on conditions
            String result = provider.getString();
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    interface StringProvider {
        String getString();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public StringProvider stringProviderOne() {
            return () -> "one";
        }

        @Bean
        public StringProvider stringProviderTwo() {
            return () -> "two";
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, Spring will inject a list of StringProvider beans, and you can iterate through them in your test method. You can then dynamically check conditions and create objects based on the actual implementations of StringProvider. This way, you don't need to deal with Class objects in your configuration.

Comment: You may check out the answer I posted to see what I meant

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion about what I'm trying to do. Let me clarify it

Imagine you receive a request with some `Authorization` header. Depending on the scheme, you may extract an `Authentication` object differently. Since you may want to approach it in an OOP way, you may have some abstract `Authenticator` supertype with `BasicAuthenticator` and `BearerAuthenticator` subtypes. I thought, "Wouldn't it be peachy if my client code could look like this"

```java
        String authorizationHeaderString = "bearer 1234567890";
        AuthorizationHeader authorizationHeader = new AuthorizationHeader(authorizationHeaderString);
        Authentication authentication = authenticators.findAuthenticatorFor(authorizationHeader)
                .buildAuthentication(); // notice I don't pass anything anymore
```

Well, I did it!

But there's a price to pay. I couldn't find a way around those dummy headers that I had to pass in `@Bean` methods

As for the question title, I simply created a separate bean that collected all beans of a type, mapped them to their respective classes, and returned a list of `Class` objects (though Java generics caused me pain)

Anyway, I hope you appreciate it. I think it's, on balance, not bad

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import java.util.List;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GenericTest.Config.class)
public class GenericTest {
    @Autowired
    Authenticators authenticators;

    @Test
    void test() {
        String authorizationHeaderString = "bearer 1234567890";
        AuthorizationHeader authorizationHeader = new AuthorizationHeader(authorizationHeaderString);
        Authentication authentication = authenticators.findAuthenticatorFor(authorizationHeader)
                .buildAuthentication();
        System.out.println(authentication);
    }

    @Getter
    static class AuthorizationHeader {
        private final String scheme;
        private final String credentials;

        public AuthorizationHeader(String authorizationHeaderString) {
            String trimmedHeader = authorizationHeaderString.trim();
            int indexOfSpace = trimmedHeader.indexOf(" ");
            String schemeSubstring = trimmedHeader.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
            String credentialsSubstring = trimmedHeader.substring(indexOfSpace).trim();

            this.scheme = schemeSubstring;
            this.credentials = credentialsSubstring;
        }
    }

    abstract static class Authenticator {
        protected String header;

        Authenticator(String header) {
            this.header = header;
        }

        abstract Authentication buildAuthentication();
    }

    static class BearerAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        BearerAuthenticator(String header) {
            super(header);
        }

        static String getHandledScheme() {
            return "bearer";
        }

        @Override
        Authentication buildAuthentication() {
            return new TestingAuthenticationToken("bearer token prncipal", null);
        }
    }

    static class BasicAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        BasicAuthenticator(String header) {
            super(header);
        }

        static String getHandledScheme() {
            return "basic";
        }

        @Override
        Authentication buildAuthentication() {
            return new TestingAuthenticationToken("basic token prncipal", null);
        }
    }

    record Authenticators(List<? extends Class<? extends Authenticator>> authenticatorClasses) {
        Authenticator findAuthenticatorFor(AuthorizationHeader authorizationHeader) {
            Class<? extends Authenticator> authenticatorClass = authenticatorClasses.stream()
                    .filter(authClass ->
                            ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(authClass, "getHandledScheme")
                                    .toString()
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(authorizationHeader.getScheme()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow();
            return ReflectionUtils.newInstance(authenticatorClass, authorizationHeader.getScheme());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean(autowireCandidate=false)
        Authenticator bearerAuthenticator() {
            return new BearerAuthenticator("dummy header");
        }

        @Bean(autowireCandidate=false)
        Authenticator basicAuthenticator() {
            return new BasicAuthenticator("dummy header");
        }

        @Bean
        List<? extends Class<? extends Authenticator>> authenticatorClasses(List<Authenticator> authenticators) {
            return authenticators.stream()
                    .map(a -> (Class<? extends Authenticator>) a.getClass())
                    .toList();
        }

        @Bean
        Authenticators authenticators(List<? extends Class<? extends Authenticator>> authenticatorClasses) {
            return new Authenticators(authenticatorClasses);
        }
    }
}
```

Though I have to admit, I don't really have to inject a list of classes to do that. Besides, I still need to create those dummy instances. If Spring allowed me to inject bean class objects directly, it would be a bit easier. It has those bean definitions with Class information anyway (though, it's more complicated with Java config since you can't know a return type in Java before you run the method, `@Bean` or not)

Comment: Is this an answer or an edit to the question? I'm a hard time figuring that out

Comment: @knittl it's an asnwer with an edit flavor to it

Comment: Re *"There's some confusion about what I'm trying to do"*: That belongs in the question. [Stack Overflow is *** ***not*** *** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). It isn't recorded conversation, follow-up responses, and change logs. The question should be as if it was written right now. Alternatively, a new question.

Comment: What's an "edit flavor"? If you have something to edit, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77979616/edit). If you have an answer, post an answer. Don't post updates to your question as answers.