# Can't return List<Class<? extends T>> in a method with return type List<Class<? extends T>>

Tags: java, generics

Can you explain the compiler's logic? Why doesn't this work

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.misc;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.authorizationHeader.AuthorizationHeader;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import java.util.List;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GenericTest.Config.class)
public class GenericTest {
    @Autowired
    List<Class<? extends Authenticator>> authenticatorClasses;

    @Test
    void test() {
        String authorizationHeaderString = "bearer 1234567890";
        AuthorizationHeader authorizationHeader = new AuthorizationHeader(authorizationHeaderString);
        Class<? extends Authenticator> authenticatorClass = authenticatorClasses.stream()
                .filter(authClass -> 
                        ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(authClass, "getHandledScheme")
                        .toString()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(authorizationHeader.getScheme()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow();
        Authenticator authenticator = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(authenticatorClass, authorizationHeader.getScheme());
        Authentication authentication = authenticator.buildAuthentication();
        System.out.println();
    }

    abstract static class Authenticator {
        protected String header;

        Authenticator(String header) {
            this.header = header;
        }

        abstract String getHandledScheme();

        abstract Authentication buildAuthentication();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public Authenticator bearerAuthenticator() {
            return new Authenticator("dummy header") {
                @Override
                String getHandledScheme() {
                    return "bearer";
                }

                @Override
                Authentication buildAuthentication() {
                    return new TestingAuthenticationToken("bearer token prncipal", null);
                }
            };
        }

        @Bean
        public Authenticator basicAuthenticator() {
            return new Authenticator("dummy header") {
                @Override
                String getHandledScheme() {
                    return "basic";
                }

                @Override
                Authentication buildAuthentication() {
                    return new TestingAuthenticationToken("basic token prncipal", null);
                }
            };
        }
        @Bean
        public List<Class<? extends Authenticator>> stringProviderClasses(List<Authenticator> authenticators) {
            return authenticators.stream()
                    .map(a -> (Class<? extends  Authenticator>) a.getClass())
                    .toList();
        }
    }
}
```

but this does

```java
// the rest is the same

        @Bean
        public List<? extends Class<? extends Authenticator>> stringProviderClasses(List<Authenticator> authenticators) {
            return authenticators.stream()
                    .map(a -> (Class<? extends  Authenticator>) a.getClass())
                    .toList();
        }
```

Let's cut javac some slack and forget that `Class` is a final class so `? extends Class` is bull****. Even then, how, in what way is the first example not type-safe? `map()` returns a `Stream` of `Class<? extends  Authenticator>`. `toList()` simply turns a generic `Stream` into a generic `List` so the result perfectly matches the return type, `List<Class<? extends Authenticator>>`

What is javac concerned about, exactly?

Comment: I think. the issue you're encountering is related to generic type inference and wildcard usage.

Comment: Basically, the solution which is working fine, you used a wildcard in the return type: 
List<? extends Class<? extends Authenticator>>. The wildcard allows the compiler to be more flexible in terms of the generic type. It means that the list can contain classes that extend Authenticator, but the exact type is not specified. This flexibility resolves the type mismatch issue encountered in the first case.

By using wildcards, you essentially tell the compiler that you are returning a list of classes where each class is a subtype of Authenticator, but you are not specifying the exact subtype.

Comment: Just for your reference, don't get confused with term 'Wildcard. : The question mark (?) is known as the wildcard in generic programming. It represents an unknown type. (source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcards-in-java/)

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting and where are you getting the said error?

Comment: [`ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(authClass, "getHandledScheme")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#invokeMethod(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) invokes a `static` method. You would need to pass an object of the said class if you want to invoke a non-static method.

Comment: @Zohair `? extends Authenticator` is present in both return types

Comment: @dan1stiscrying let's focus on the compilation phase. If you want a perfectly runnable version of it, you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77980486/23299948)

Answer (score 1):

Java is worried about the ability to `add()` something that isn't appropriate.

This, and to a lesser extent the fact that `? extends Class` is itself covering concerns you don't think about because `Class` is final, explains why to your eyes/brains `javac` appears to be doing whatever the compiler equivalent is of huffing paint fumes.

Because you're not calling `add()` on that list that is returned. You aren't thinking about it whatsoever.

A retread of the basic lessons of generics in terms of lists, avoiding all such pitfalls where javac is thinking of things that don't even apply to the situation:

Given:

- `List<Number>` (invariant)
- `List<? extends Number>` (covariant)
- `List<? super Number>` (contravariant)
- `List` (raw)

---

- invariant (`List<Number>`) is restrictive in what it accepts: a `List<Integer>` **is not** a `List<Number>`! However, it is permissive in what you can do to it: You can call `.add(someInt)` on this list, and `.get(someIdx)` is typed `Number`.
- covariant (`List<? extends Number>`) is more permissive in what it accepts - a `List<Integer>` is also acceptable, as is a `List<Double>`. Of course, that means that you cannot do anything to a `List<? extends Number>` unless that operation is as sensible on a `List<Double>` as it is on a `List<Integer>`, and, as a result, **you cannot call `.add`, at all, on a `List<? extends Number>`**. Because nothing you can pass to `.add()` is valid for *both* `List<Integer>` as well as `List<Double>`. Except the literal `null` which, indeed, is legal, but mostly useless. `.get(idx)`, however, is fine: That gives you a `Number`. Because `.get(idx)` on a `List<Double>` gives you a Number (a Double, in fact, which is a Number), and the same goes for a `List<Integer>`.
- contravariant (`List<? super Number>`) is permissive in a different way - you can pass a `List<Number>` as well as a `List<Object>`, and `add` is unencumbered - you can add numbers just fine: `.add(someInt)` works. Because that is an operation that is valid for a `List<Number>` and *also* for a `List<Object>`. However, `.get` is encumbered: `.get(idx)` is typed `Object`, which is the equivalent of 'you cannot call `add`' here. You can call it only because java guarantees that regardless of circumstance, we know, at least, that it is an object. The same principles apply here: What things hold regardless of whether the actual object is a `List<Object>` or `List<Number>`? Well, `.get(idx)` returns at least `Object` but we can't say any more than that. However, `.add(someNumberInstance)` works on either one so that's fine.
- raw/legacy (`List` with no `<>` at all) is permissive in all ways: You can `add` whatever you want. But, the compiler no longer vouches for the type safety of what you do now.

Using that logic and applying it to your situation, it becomes clear what javac is worried about:

It is worried that you can call `.add(someInstanceOfMyAuthenticator)` on a `List<Class<MyAuthenticator>>` (which is a thing that 'fits' `List<Class<? extends Authenticator>`). `javac` doesn't know if:

- The thing that produced this list retains a reference to the produced list and e.g. saved it in a field or some such. It is allowed to do that. And code analysis is pointless - a future update might do that, javac considers any changing of method signatures backwards incompatible unless done very carefully, but you can change implementations anytime you want.
- The list supports `add`. The compiler doesn't know if the list produced is read-only. It has to operate under the assumption that it might not be.
- Anybody is going to call `add` on this produced list.

So, worst case scenario:

- The code that makes this list saves it someplace, and expects, naturally, that all elements inside it are `Class<?>` - that question mark means: Do not know (not 'anything goes' - 'some specific thing goes and I do not know what that specific thing is'). Hence, the code that gets this list cannot add anything to it whatsoever; how could the compiler possibly ensure the things added are `Class<?>` - it can't, it doesn't know what that question mark stands for.
- The code that gets this list calls `add` on it anyway, or is planning to later.
- .. and adds a thing that *is not* a `Class<?>`, whatever that ? stands for...
- and then the code that produced the list goes through it and finds a thing that should never have been in there.

About half of those bullet points don't even apply to the code, but, the compiler doesn't know it.