# How does getClass() get away with its erratic behavior?

Tags: java

`getClass()` returns `Class<?>`:

```java
public final Class<?> getClass() {...}
```

yet this doesn't require a cast:

```java
Number n = 0;
Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
```

From the method's javadoc:

> The **actual result type** is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

What is "the actual result type"?

I thought there's only one "result type" for a method in Java, its *return type* (which is in this case `Class<?>`)

["The Java Language Specification mandates that this method is treated in a special way by the compiler"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19333305/23299948).

**But how does it work?** *<-- this is the focus*

Does javac simply insert an "unchecked cast" for the one thing?

Does javac's code have some hard-coded "if method is called getClass, let it do whateverit wants"?

This compiles:

```java
Class<? extends String> stringClass = Stream.of("str")
    .map(s -> s.getClass())
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow();
```

This doesn't:

```java
Class<? extends String> stringClass = Stream.of("str")
    .map(Object::getClass)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow();
```

This works, even though `String` doesn't even override `getClass()` (even if it did, it's not how method references work):

```java
Class<? extends String> stringClass = Stream.of("str")
    .map(String::getClass)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow();
```

If you try to navigate to that `String::getClass` method, you'll see

```java
// a regular object.getClass()!

@IntrinsicCandidate
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

Should I jump through all kinds of hoops to please that javac, while `getClass()` gets special treatment?

How is it possible?

Comment: do you know what inheritance is?

Comment: When you see `native`, that's usually an indication that the method is handled through either JNI/JNA, or it's a shoe-in method provided by the JVM. Either way, the actual implementation of the method leaves the Java space and is usually C++ code. The big hint would be "erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.", giving you the difference between `String::getClass` and `Object::getClass`. Note that static methods _are_ inherited, but never overridden.

Comment: The language doesn't support naming the return type <? extends |T|>. So it is a special method, with special treatment. What are you trying to do that would be simpler if you could create a method the same as getClass?

Comment: Class is a special type of object.  getClass() is a special system-level method.  Of course it doesn’t behave like most other methods.  Perhaps if you ask a question about the specific “hoops” you have to jump through, we can help.

Comment: Then edit this question and add details about those hoops.

Comment: Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77981253/1831987) seems to cover your issue well.

Comment: What is the 1 specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is "the actual result type"?
>
> I thought there's only one "result type" for a method in Java, its return type (which is in this case `Class<?>`)

Every method has exactly one return type, yes, which may be either a primitive type, an unparameterized reference type, a raw parameterized type, or a parameterized type combined with bounds on the type parameters.

**What the doc is saying is that `Object.getClass()` is a special case** whose return type cannot be expressed exactly in Java syntax.  It *is not* actually `Class<?>` (with `Object` as implicit upper parameter bound).  It is `Class<?>` with an upper parameter bound determined from the invocation target. That's much like

```
<T> Class<? extends T> getClassOfObject(T obj) {
    // ...
}
```

. In fact, that method's body could be simply `return obj.getClass();`.
But `Object.getClass()` itself cannot be expressed in those terms because (i) class `Object` is not parameterized, and (ii) there is no useful way to hang a type parameter on the method, given that it accepts no regular parameters.  Understand, then, that it is not the return type itself that is special, but rather how the bounds on its parameter type are determined.

> But how does it work? Does javac simply bite the bullet and insert an "unchecked cast" (the one thing it hates)?

There is no discrimination at the bytecode level among references to different types.  When an unchecked cast is compiled, the only representation is a `checkcast` instruction, which is effectively an *assertion* that the referrent object is of a class (considering raw type only) compatible with the specified (raw) type.  The compiler doesn't like emitting those, and code that passes its type checks does not require them.  So what the compiler does in the case you ask about is *nothing*.  It does not need to emit any particular bytecode at all to accept the result of a given `getClass()` call as being type-correct.

More generally, ***the point of type parameterization is to make type checking the responsibility of the compiler***, and to equip it adequately for that task.  What the compiler detests is code that requires it to emit a `checkcast` instruction in the generated bytecode.  As far as I am aware, unchecked casts in Java source code are the only things that require that.

You go on to observe that Java 21's type analysis does not handle method reference `Object::getClass` the same as lambda `s -> s.getClass()`.  Ok.  I didn't know that before, and I acknowledge that it's surprising.  That might be a good subject for a defect report if there isn't already one addressing it.

You furthermore observe that `String::getClass` is analyzed differently than `Object::getClass`, even though `String` inherits its `getClass()` method from `Object`.  Ok.  This is a little surprising in view of the previous, but isn't it what you would expect in light of the special treatment afforded to `getClass()`?

> Should I jump through all kinds of hoops to please that javac, while `getClass()` gets special treatment

Oh, please.  `getClass()` is a known quantity for the compiler.  That's what enables special treatment, and **that in turn provides a convenience to programmers**, including you.  And yes, it *is* special treatment, built into the compiler.  You cannot get the same for your own classes unless you want to write your own Java compiler.  Are you seriously complaining about Java making things easier for you?

Type parameterization and compile-time type checking have both advantages and disadvantages, but I doubt many programmers who remember having only raw types to work with would go back to those days.  I know I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your javadoc quote, `getClass()` return type is `Class<? extends |X|>` (not `Class<?>`), where `|X|` is the the erasure of the expression's static type (see [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).
In your first example, `getClass()` effectively returns 'Class<? extends Number>' matching the assignment type.
The "special treatment" that getClass gets is in the assignment of '|X|'.